# multiview doesnot update with the update value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have one gridview on the left and I have Multiview pane on the right. Basically what I am trying to do is when the use click select in the gridview, the information of that row will display in the Multiview. 
I have two view.

View 1 contains label saying please select row to view full details.

View 2 basically retrieving all the necessary data.

The problem is, in my view 2, I do allow user to update the data. When the user updates the data and save, the view will go back to its initial view. And when the user click on the same row, it will then display the updated information.
How can I do such that when they save the changes, the view will show the updated information?

I have tried putting updatepanel but it does not work too.

CODE BEHIND:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        xxBLL schBLL = new xxBLL ();
        GVFBAcc.DataSource = schBLL.getInfo();
        GVFBAcc.DataBind();
        MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }
```

protected void GVFBAcc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        try
        {
            string Selectedid = GVFBAcc.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;//get user id
            int selectedIdtoPass = Convert.ToInt32(Selectedid);

            xxBLL getRecord = new xxBLL ();
            addInfo InfoRetrieve = new addInfo ();
            InfoRetrieve = getRecord.getDetail(selectedIdtoPass);

            lbid.Text = Convert.ToString(InfoRetrieve .info_id1);
            lbType.Text = InfoRetrieve .type;

            lbName.Text = InfoRetrieve .name;
            lbAbb.Text = InfoRetrieve .abb;


            MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbMessage.Visible = true;
            lbMessage.Text = "Please select a Row.";
        }
    }
```

protected void editInfo_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

```
    {
        MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        string cIcon = editInfo.ImageUrl;

        if (cIcon.Equals("~/images/edit.png"))
        {
            editInfo.ImageUrl = "~/images/save.png";

            lblEdit.Text = "";

            tbName.Text = lbName.Text;
            tbAbb.Text = lbAbb.Text;
            tbtype.Text = lbType.Text;

            lbName.Visible = false;
            lbAbb.Visible = false;
            lbType.Visible = true;


            tbName.Visible = true;
            tbAbb.Visible = true;
            tbtype.Visible = false;


        }
        else if (cIcon.Equals("~/images/save.png"))
        {

            addInfo[] update = new addInfo[1];

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(lbid.Text);
            string name = tbName.Text;
            string abb = tbAbb.Text;


            addInfo updated = new addInfo(name, id, abb);

            update[0] = updated;

            xxBLL obj = new xxBLL ();
            if (obj.updateDetail(update))
            {

                editInfo.ImageUrl = "~/images/edit.png";

                lbName.Visible = true;
                lbAbb.Visible = true;
                lbType.Visible = true;


                tbName.Visible = false;
                tbAbb.Visible = false;
                tbtype.Visible = false;


                lblEdit.Text = "Saved";
                lblEdit.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                tbName.Text = lbName.Text;
                tbAbb.Text = lbAbb.Text;
                tbtype.Text = lbType.Text;



            }

        }



    }
```

When the user updates the data and save, the view will go back to its initial view. And when the user click on the same row, it will then display the updated information. How can I do such that when they save the changes, the view will show the updated information?

or alternative How do i call the button click event at page load so that when the user clicks the save button, it will display the updated infomation

Comment: have added the code above. @MAdeelKhalid

Comment: Once your update is completed, you need to fetch and re-bind the grid. Include these lines `GVFBAcc.DataSource = schBLL.getInfo();
        GVFBAcc.DataBind();` as part of your `if (obj.updateDetail(update))` code block

Comment: I have tried and still it did not display the updated value in the View Panel. I have to select the item on gridview and then it will display the updated value. is there a way for me to click the save button and straight away it will show the updated infomation on the view panel @Thangadurai